# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.julman99.gsonfire.GsonFireBuilder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with the import of the Gson Library in my project. I switched from eclipse to android studio and I have this problem. Do you know how to fix that?

I set this in the gradle dependencies

```
compile 'io.gsonfire:gson-fire:1.0.1' <- third attempt
//compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' <- second attempt
//compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' <- first attempt
```

AStudio throws this while I was trying to run my app "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.julman99.gsonfire.GsonFireBuilder"

Thanks

Comment: Are you importing the package in your Java file with `import com.google.gson.Gson;` ?

Comment: These are my imports: 
import com.github.julman99.gsonfire.GsonFireBuilder;
import com.github.julman99.gsonfire.annotations.ExposeMethodResult;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

Answer (score 1):

starting from gson-fire 1.0 the package name changed. Instead of `com.github.julman99.gsonfire`, it is `io.gsonfire`

Try changing all the reference to the old package and let me know if it works.